# How to calculate the length of a string in Apache Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

In pig, the `substring` function has three arguments, I need to get the substring from 4th position to length of the string.

So I specified:

```
substring(division,4,string.length(division))
```

It is showing error  `Could not resolve string.LENGTH using imports:`.
How to find the length of string in pig?

Comment: Could you post your error and your code?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [SIZE](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#size) for that.

SUBSTRING(division,4,SIZE(division))

Comment: these is not solving problem

Answer (score 2):

The responses provided earlier didn't work out for me. What worked was:

```
SUBSTRING(division,4,(int)SIZE(division))
```

Notice the `int` cast.

Answer (score 0):

`SIZE()` is the function to use which internally calls `String.length()`

So in your case (as Frederic says):

```
SUBSTRING(division,4,SIZE(division))
```

Answer (score 0):

i was also getting same error . After trying for almost 1 day i found solution , solution is that , you should have to do following code ,

```
REGISTER '/usr/local/piggybank.jar';
maindata = LOAD '/user/pig/storm/StormEvents_details-ftp_v1.0_d1950_c20170120.csv' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(',','NO_MULTILINE','UNIX','SKIP_INPUT_HEADER');

B = foreach maindata generate (int)$20 as INJURIES_DIRECT,(int)$21 as INJURIES_INDIRECT,(int)$22 as DEATHS_DIRECT,(int)$23 as DEATHS_INDIRECT,(chararray)$24 as DAMAGE_PROPERTY,(int)$10 as YEAR,(chararray)$11 as MONTH_NAME,(int)$0 as BEGIN_YEARMONTH;
k = foreach B generate org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.LENGTH(DAMAGE_PROPERTY) as len;
```

So here if you can see in these code you have to include your field in place of DAMAGE_PROPERTY . So the solution of our problem is ,

```
org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.LENGTH(DAMAGE_PROPERTY) as len;
```

Now for substring you can do these kind of code , you can change it accordingly your string name ,

```
substringdata = foreach B generate SUBSTRING(DAMAGE_PROPERTY,0,org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.string.LENGTH(DAMAGE_PROPERTY)-1) as substr;
```

I think it should solve issue .